# How to convert Pandas dataframe to np.array while preserving the index?

Tags: python, pandas

For example, I have a small set of data (from movielens)

check.csv

```
userId,movieId,rating,timestamp
1,31,2.5,1260759144
1,1029,3.0,1260759179
1,1061,3.0,1260759182
2,17,5.0,835355681
3,267,3.0,1298861761
3,296,4.5,1298862418
3,318,5.0,1298862121
```

If I do

```
rating = pd.read_csv('check.csv')

Y = pd.pivot_table(rating, values='rating', index=['movieId'], columns=['userId']).values
```

it will create 3*7 matrix. But what I want is a 3*1061 (having userId as column index and movie as row index). How to achieve that 3*1061 matrix
how can I make a 1061*3 matrix S, with S[31][1]=2.5 S[1029][1]=3 etc. and all the missing entries equals zero.

Comment: Why do you expect a Dataframe with 7 rows to be converted to a matrix with 1061 rows? Where are the other rows coming from?

Comment: I expect all of those be zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.read_csv('check.csv')
Y = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['rating'], index=['movieId'], columns=['userId'])

            rating
 userId     1       2      3
 movieId
   31      2.5      0      0
   1029    3.0      0      0
   1061    3.0      0      0
   17       0       5.0    0
   296      0       0     4.0
```

remaining value will come according to csv values. More details http://pbpython.com/pandas-pivot-table-explained.html

Comment: But how can I make a 1061*3 matrix S, with S[31][1]=2.5 S[1029][1]=3 etc. and all the missing entries equals zero.